# Quais comandos para GitHub no Terminal do Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, git, github

Tenho um PC em casa(Windows) e na faculdade utilizo Linux Mint. Em casa instalei um programa do GitHub para desktop, e pelo que vi só tem para Windows, e apenas 64 bits diga-se de passagem.

Comecei a usar o GitHub nos últimos dias em casa e tudo ocorreu bem, criei um repositório a partir de uma pasta já existente, dou commit e sync normalmente pelo programa. Quando entro no site lá estão os arquivos corretamente. Se eu fizer alguma mudança pelo site, basta dar sync que o arquivo atualiza no meu PC.

Procurei o mesmo programa para instalar no Linux mas não encontrei. Achei apenas coisas para serem feitas pelo terminal, porém não sou muito familiarizado com ele. Fiz alguns testes aqui de acordo com o que achei na internet, porém a única coisa que consegui fazer foi um git clone //diretorio. Porém uma única vez(a partir da segunda dava erro).

Gostaria de saber como eu faço, a partir do Linux, para baixar os arquivos do GitHub já sincronizando com o que tenho no Linux, e após fazer alguma alteração em algum arquivo, conseguir upar a pasta inteira e sincronizar o site com esta pasta. Assim como faço no Windows. Quais seriam os comandos necessários para isto? Desde já obrigado.

Link do GitHub: https://github.com/EmanoelFraguas/GitProject

Comment: Os comando Git não pertencem ao linux, os comandos Git são comandos "Git e pronto", tendo Git instalado no sistema operacional seja qual for, os comandos serão os mesmos, a não ser que seja uma fork propria modificada do "cliente git", o que falta pra ti é instalar o cliente "Git".

Comment: Para se familiarizar, use o `git bash` no windows, ele é instalado junto com o Git GUI (é obrigatório). No mais, leia [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Qual distro do linux está você esta usando `Ubuntu`?

Comment: Eu uso Linux Mint na faculdade

Comment: Aqui tem um manual bem basico para usar na linha de comando: https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

Answer (score 1):

Para Linux tem um ambiente gráfico, que dá para Windows/Linux/MacOS chamado Git Kraken. Interface muito simples e intuitiva!

Comment: Eu conseguiria acessar arquivos no GitHub ou teria que fazer um outro repositorio a parte?

Comment: Através do GitKraken pode aceder a repositórios do GitHub, BitBucket e GitLabs por definição. Por isso sim, bastaria fazer o Clone do repositório graças ao link que o GitHub fornece.